# How to get parametric subset from SQL result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having SQL query `SELECT exam_id, task, variant FROM tasks WHERE exam_id=1` we get:

```
  exam_id   task    variant
  1         1       1
  1         1       2
  1         1       3
  1         2       1
  1         2       2
  1         2       3
```

On the client side we generate array of random numbers from range `[minVariant; maxVariant]`. `A = [minVariant; maxVariant]`. Xn from A is variant for nth corresponding task.

How to change SQL query so that for array of variants A = [2, 3] we would get

```
  exam_id   task    variant
  1         1       2
  1         2       3
```

for A = [1, 3]:

```
  exam_id   task    variant
  1         1       1
  1         2       3
```

for A = [a1, a2]:

```
  exam_id   task    variant
  1         1       a1
  1         2       a2
```

Having 6 different tasks and an array `[1,2,2,2,3,4]` I need to get:

```
  exam_id   task    variant
  1         1       1
  1         2       2
  1         3       2
  1         4       2
  1         5       3
  1         6       4
```

Comment: So you can have several rangers, for example (2-3 and  4-7), and you need get all rows `where variant = min/max from this ranges`? I correctly understood?

Comment: @OtoShavadze, I have a constant range (1-4), but I have an array with many numbers of variants, for example: [1,2,2,2,3,4]. Now for each task I want to get row where `variant = variant_from_variants`. For task1 I want a task with `variant=variants[0]`, for task2 I want a task with `variant=variants[1]` and so on

Comment: Lets say you have this array `[1,2,2,2,3,4]`, can you edit your question and show us, what will be desirable output from your sample table ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but looks like you are trying to and multiple conditions.

If you are asking for a list of values, try:

```
SELECT exam_id, task, variant FROM tasks WHERE exam_id=1 and variant in (2,3)
```

If you are asking how to get a range:

```
SELECT exam_id, task, variant FROM tasks WHERE exam_id=1 and variant>1 and variant<10
```

if it is something else you are trying to accomplish, please clarify

Comment: Yes, it looks like it has to be done with multiple conditions, but how to I map  variant array so that I don't do a query for each variant in the array. I can get task1 with variant1, then task2 with variant2, where my variants_array = [variant1, variant2], these are 2 separate queries. How can I map each task to a task with corresponding variant in the variants_array in a single query. Is it possible?